# codeigniter form_radio()

Tags: codeigniter

---- I have solved the radio button problem. now the problem is i need to send the value $thing->quistionNo in the controller along with the answer.---

```
    <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'things/show'); 

         foreach ($data->result()as $thing) { 



                echo $thing->questionNo.". ".$thing->question;  

                 $qno =array(
        'name'  =>   'qno',
        'id'    =>   'qno',
        'value' =>   $thing->questionNo        
        );


                //$qno = $thing->questionNo; 
                var_dump($qno);
                ?>



            <ul>
                <li>

                    <div>
<?php echo form_radio("answer", "1", (set_value("answer") == "1"));
echo $thing->option1; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>

                    <div>
<?php echo form_radio("answer", "2", (set_value("answer") == "2"));
echo $thing->option2; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>            

                <li>

                    <div>
<?php echo form_radio("answer", "3", (set_value("answer") == "3"));
echo $thing->option3; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <div>
<?php echo form_radio("answer", "4", (set_value("answer") == "4"));
echo $thing->option4; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                    <?php } 
                    echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit'), 'Submit Answer'); 
                    echo form_close();
                    ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: hi can you provide the coding part?

Comment: thanks i have solved it.but now i have new problem

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your form_submit.

form_submit has 2 parameters, which accept name and value of the input.

```
echo form_submit('oksubmit', 'Submit!');
```

which will produce:

```
<input type="submit" name="oksubmit" value="Submit!" />
```

For more information you can refer to [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: <?php echo form_radio("answer", "1");
echo $thing->option1; ?>
I have changed it, but i need pass the qno also when i will submit the form.

Comment: I have got the answer. need to submit form_hidden()